# C# WPF SQL multi-table CRUD using Entity Model and LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to use Entity Model to display multiple SQL tables to a datagrid as well as update, create and delete rows. I am having problems getting Entity Model objects from my tables after I have joined them as now the entity has more datafields than the original model object it came from. I expect the solution lies in a ViewModel of some sort however I am having trouble figuring out how to separate objects out from the ViewModel once they are combined. I have been trying to solve this problem for days and at this point I expect I will have to do some serious retooling of my code. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the Load Entity Model (Load in relation to a freight load, this has no relationship to loading anything)

```
public partial class Load
{
    public int bol_num { get; set; }
    public string pro_num { get; set; }
    public string quote_num { get; set; }
    public string ref_num { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> weight { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> pieces { get; set; }
    public string commodity { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> mileage { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> carrier_rate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> customer_rate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> driver_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> dispatch_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> customer_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> broker_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> pick_date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> pick_time { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> drop_date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> drop_time { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> last_updated_time { get; set; }
    public string load_status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> account_id { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    //Constructors
    public Load(
        int bolInt, 
        string proString, 
        string quoteString, 
        string refString, 
        double weightDouble, 
        int piecesInt, 
        string commodityString, 
        double mileageDouble, 
        decimal carrier_rateDecimal, 
        decimal customer_rateDecimal,
        int driver_idInt,
        int dispatch_idInt,
        int customer_idInt,
        int broker_idInt,
        DateTime pick_dateDateTime,
        TimeSpan pick_timeTimeSpan,
        DateTime drop_dateDateTime,
        TimeSpan drop_timeTimeSpan,
        DateTime last_updated_timeDateTime,
        string load_statusString,
        int account_idInt
        )
    {
        bol_num = bolInt;
        pro_num = proString;
        quote_num = quoteString;
        ref_num = refString;
        weight = weightDouble;
        pieces = piecesInt;
        commodity = commodityString;
        mileage = mileageDouble;
        carrier_rate = carrier_rateDecimal;
        customer_rate = customer_rateDecimal;
        driver_id = driver_idInt;
        dispatch_id = dispatch_idInt;
        customer_id = customer_idInt;
        broker_id = broker_idInt;
        pick_date = pick_dateDateTime;
        pick_time = pick_timeTimeSpan;
        drop_date = drop_dateDateTime;
        drop_time = drop_timeTimeSpan;
        last_updated_time = last_updated_timeDateTime;
        load_status = load_statusString;
        account_id = account_idInt;
    }
    //Default
    public Load()
    {

    }
}
```

}

This is the Entity Model for the Contact object

```
public partial class Contact
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Contact()
    {
        this.Accounts = new HashSet<Account>();
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string contact_name { get; set; }
    public string contact_phone { get; set; }
    public string contact_email { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

This is the function that handles adding new rows and updating existing rows

```
//Update or Create Button
    private void update_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Value Setting process
        try
        {
            //Load model
            Load loadModel = new Load();
            //Get the load data from input fields
            loadModel.bol_num = Convert.ToInt32(bol_txt.Text.Trim());
            loadModel.load_status = loadStatus_cmbo.Text;
            loadModel.pro_num = pro_txt.Text.Trim();
            loadModel.quote_num = quote_txt.Text.Trim();
            loadModel.ref_num = ref_txt.Text.Trim();
            try
            {
                loadModel.weight = Convert.ToDouble(weight_txt.Text.Trim());
            }
            catch (System.FormatException ex){ MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Invalid Pieces Entry", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);}
            try
            { 
                loadModel.pieces = Convert.ToInt32(pieces_txt.Text.Trim()); 
            }
            catch(System.FormatException ex){MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Invalid Pieces Entry", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);}

            loadModel.commodity = commodity_txt.Text.Trim();
            loadModel.mileage = Convert.ToDouble(mileage_txt.Text.Trim());
            loadModel.carrier_rate = Convert.ToDecimal(carrierRate_txt.Text.Trim());
            loadModel.customer_rate = Convert.ToDecimal(customerRate_txt.Text.Trim());

            //Pick Date & Time setter
            loadModel.pick_date = pickDate_picker.SelectedDate.Value;
            loadModel.pick_time = TimeSpanBuilder(pickAptTime_txt.Text);

            //Drop Date & Time setter
            loadModel.drop_date = dropDate_picker.SelectedDate.Value;
            loadModel.drop_time = TimeSpanBuilder(dropAptTime_txt.Text);

            loadModel.driver_id = Convert.ToInt32(driver_txt.Text.Trim());
            loadModel.dispatch_id = Convert.ToInt32(dispatch_txt.Text.Trim());
            loadModel.customer_id = Convert.ToInt32(customer_txt.Text.Trim());
            loadModel.broker_id = Convert.ToInt32(broker_txt.Text.Trim());

            //Last updated
            loadModel.last_updated_time = DateTime.Now;

            //Save the load to the database
            using(HOTLOADDBEntities HOTLOADEntity = new HOTLOADDBEntities())
            {
                if(loadModel.bol_num == 0)//Insert
                {
                    HOTLOADEntity.Loads.Add(loadModel);
                    Clear();
                    MessageBox.Show("Saved Succesfully");
                }
                else//Update
                {
                    HOTLOADEntity.Entry(loadModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    Clear();
                }
                //Save the changes
                HOTLOADEntity.SaveChanges();
                Search();
            }

        }
        //Entity Model Exception handler
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation(
                          "Class: {0}, Property: {1}, Error: {2}",
                          validationErrors.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName,
                          validationError.PropertyName,
                          validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the function that selects objects from the DataGrid which is now non-functional due to me adding join functionality to my Search function.

```
private void LoadBoard_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (LoadBoard.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            //Load model
            Load loadModel = (Load)LoadBoard.SelectedItem;
            using (HOTLOADDBEntities HOTLOADEntity = new HOTLOADDBEntities())
            {
                loadModel = HOTLOADEntity.Loads.Where(x => x.bol_num == loadModel.bol_num).FirstOrDefault();
                bol_txt.Text = loadModel.bol_num.ToString();
                loadStatus_cmbo.SelectedIndex = ParseStatus(loadModel.load_status);
                pro_txt.Text = loadModel.pro_num.ToString();
                quote_txt.Text = loadModel.quote_num.ToString();
                ref_txt.Text = loadModel.ref_num.ToString();
                weight_txt.Text = loadModel.weight.ToString();
                pieces_txt.Text = loadModel.pieces.ToString();
                commodity_txt.Text = loadModel.commodity.ToString();
                mileage_txt.Text = loadModel.mileage.ToString();
                carrierRate_txt.Text = loadModel.carrier_rate.ToString();
                customerRate_txt.Text = loadModel.customer_rate.ToString();

                //Dates & Times
                pickDate_picker.Text = loadModel.pick_date.ToString();
                pickAptTime_txt.Text = TimeStringBuilder(loadModel.pick_time.Value);

                dropDate_picker.Text = loadModel.drop_date.ToString();
                dropAptTime_txt.Text = TimeStringBuilder(loadModel.drop_time.Value);

                driver_txt.Text = loadModel.driver_id.ToString();
                dispatch_txt.Text = loadModel.dispatch_id.ToString();
                customer_txt.Text = loadModel.customer_id.ToString();
                broker_txt.Text = loadModel.broker_id.ToString();

                lastUpdated_lbl.Content = "Last Updated: " + loadModel.last_updated_time;
            }
            //Change Update/New button text
            update_btn.Content = "Update Load";

            //Enable copy & delete buttons
            delete_btn.IsEnabled = true;
            copy_btn.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

This is the function that handles database queries

```
private void Search()
    {
        HOTLOADEntity = new HOTLOADDBEntities();

        //Timespan handling
        TimeSpan pickTimeStart = TimeSpan.Zero;
        TimeSpan pickTimeEnd = TimeSpan.Zero;
        TimeSpan dropTimeStart = TimeSpan.Zero;
        TimeSpan dropTimeEnd = TimeSpan.Zero;
        try { pickTimeStart = TimeSpanBuilder(pickTimeStartSearch_txt.Text); }catch (System.Exception){//Ignore
        }
        try{ pickTimeEnd = TimeSpanBuilder(pickTimeEndSearch_txt.Text); }catch (System.Exception){//Ignore
        }
        try { dropTimeStart = TimeSpanBuilder(dropTimeStartSearch_txt.Text); }catch (System.Exception){//Ignore
        }
        try { dropTimeEnd = TimeSpanBuilder(dropTimeEndSearch_txt.Text); }catch (System.Exception){//Ignore
        }

        var matchedLoads = (
                        from loadsTable in HOTLOADEntity.Loads
                        join driversTable in HOTLOADEntity.Contacts on loadsTable.driver_id equals driversTable.id
                        /*
                        where 
                        loadsTable.bol_num.ToString().Contains(bolSearch_txt.Text) &&
                        loadsTable.pro_num.ToString().Contains(proSearch_txt.Text) &&
                        loadsTable.quote_num.ToString().Contains(quoteSearch_txt.Text) &&
                        loadsTable.ref_num.ToString().Contains(refSearch_txt.Text) &&

                        //Pick Date search terms
                        ((pickDateStart_dtpckr.SelectedDate == null || loadsTable.pick_date >= pickDateStart_dtpckr.SelectedDate) &&

                        (pickDateEnd_dtpckr.SelectedDate == null || loadsTable.pick_date <= pickDateEnd_dtpckr.SelectedDate)) &&

                        //Pick Time search terms
                        ((pickTimeStartSearch_txt.Text == null || pickTimeStart == TimeSpan.Zero || loadsTable.pick_time.Value >= pickTimeStart) &&
                        (pickTimeEndSearch_txt.Text == null || pickTimeEnd == TimeSpan.Zero || loadsTable.pick_time.Value <= pickTimeEnd)) &&

                        //Drop Date Search terms
                        ((dropDateStart_dtpckr.SelectedDate == null || loadsTable.drop_date >= dropDateStart_dtpckr.SelectedDate) &&

                        (dropDateEnd_dtpckr.SelectedDate == null || loadsTable.drop_date <= dropDateEnd_dtpckr.SelectedDate)) &&

                        //Drop Time search terms
                        ((dropTimeStartSearch_txt.Text == null || dropTimeStart == TimeSpan.Zero || loadsTable.drop_time.Value >= dropTimeStart) &&
                        (dropTimeEndSearch_txt.Text == null || dropTimeEnd == TimeSpan.Zero || loadsTable.drop_time.Value <= dropTimeEnd))
                        */
                        select new
                        {
                            bol_num = loadsTable.bol_num,
                            load_status = loadsTable.load_status,
                            pro_num = loadsTable.pro_num,
                            quote_num = loadsTable.quote_num,
                            ref_num = loadsTable.ref_num,
                            weight = loadsTable.weight,
                            pieces = loadsTable.pieces,
                            commodity = loadsTable.commodity,
                            mileage = loadsTable.mileage,
                            carrier_rate = loadsTable.carrier_rate,
                            customer_rate = loadsTable.customer_rate,
                            pick_date = loadsTable.pick_date,
                            pick_time = loadsTable.pick_time,
                            drop_date = loadsTable.drop_date,
                            drop_time = loadsTable.drop_time,
                            last_updated_time = loadsTable.last_updated_time,
                            driver_id = loadsTable.driver_id,
                            driver_name = driversTable.contact_name,
                            driver_phone = driversTable.contact_phone,
                            driver_email = driversTable.contact_email,
                            dispatch_id = loadsTable.dispatch_id,
                            customer_id = loadsTable.customer_id,
                            broker_id = loadsTable.broker_id,
                            account_id = loadsTable.account_id
                        }
                        ).ToList();

        LoadBoard.ItemsSource = matchedLoads;
    }
```

Not sure if this will be relevant but this is the associated XAML for the DataGrid

```
<DataGrid Name="LoadBoard" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="Cornsilk" Background="Ivory" IsReadOnly="True" MouseDoubleClick="LoadBoard_MouseDoubleClick">
                <!--Datagrid Columns-->
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="bolColumn" Header="BOL#" Binding="{Binding bol_num}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="statusColumn" Header="Status" Binding="{Binding load_status}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="proColumn" Header="Pro#" Binding="{Binding pro_num}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="quoteColumn" Header="Quote#" Binding="{Binding quote_num}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="refColumn" Header="Ref" Binding="{Binding ref_num}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="weightColumn" Header="Weight" Binding="{Binding weight}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="piecesColumn" Header="Pieces" Binding="{Binding pieces}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="commodityColumn" Header="Commodity" Binding="{Binding commodity}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="mileageColumn" Header="Mileage" Binding="{Binding mileage}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="carrierColumn" Header="Carrier Rate" Binding="{Binding carrier_rate}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="customerRateColumn" Header="Customer Rate" Binding="{Binding customer_rate}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="pickDateColumn" Header="Pick Date" Binding="{Binding pick_date, StringFormat= \{0:MM/dd/yyyy\}}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="pickTimeColumn" Header="Pick Time" Binding="{Binding pick_time, StringFormat=hh\\:mm}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dropDateColumn" Header="Drop Date" Binding="{Binding drop_date, StringFormat= \{0:MM/dd/yyyy\}}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dropTimeColumn" Header="Drop Time" Binding="{Binding drop_time, StringFormat=hh\\:mm}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lastUpdatedColumn" Header="Last Updated" Binding="{Binding last_updated_time}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="driverNameColumn" Header="Driver Name" Binding="{Binding driver_name}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="driverPhoneColumn" Header="Driver Phone" Binding="{Binding driver_phone}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="driverEmailColumn" Header="Driver Email" Binding="{Binding driver_email}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DispatchColumn" Header="Dispatch" Binding="{Binding dispatch_id}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="CustomerColumn" Header="Customer" Binding="{Binding customer_id}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="BrokerColumn" Header="Broker" Binding="{Binding broker_id}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: well the common solution is to have separate classes for storage and presentation levels and map between them when required

Comment: How do I do that? I've tried using a view model but I was unable to get CRUD operations to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up re-attempting the View Model solution and got it working finally. Here is the code I used to do so.

View Model class

```
class ViewModel
{
    //Load Fields
    public int bol_num { get; set; }
    public string pro_num { get; set; }
    public string quote_num { get; set; }
    public string ref_num { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> weight { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> pieces { get; set; }
    public string commodity { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> mileage { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> carrier_rate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> customer_rate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> driver_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> dispatch_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> customer_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> broker_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> pick_date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> pick_time { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> drop_date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> drop_time { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> last_updated_time { get; set; }
    public string load_status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> account_id { get; set; }

    //Driver Fields
    public string driverContact_name { get; set; }
    public string driverContact_phone { get; set; }
    public string driverContact_email { get; set; }
}
```

Modified Search function

```
private void Search()
    {
        HOTLOADEntity = new HOTLOADDBEntities();

        //Timespan handling
        TimeSpan pickTimeStart = TimeSpan.Zero;
        TimeSpan pickTimeEnd = TimeSpan.Zero;
        TimeSpan dropTimeStart = TimeSpan.Zero;
        TimeSpan dropTimeEnd = TimeSpan.Zero;
        try { pickTimeStart = TimeSpanBuilder(pickTimeStartSearch_txt.Text); }catch (System.Exception){//Ignore
        }
        try{ pickTimeEnd = TimeSpanBuilder(pickTimeEndSearch_txt.Text); }catch (System.Exception){//Ignore
        }
        try { dropTimeStart = TimeSpanBuilder(dropTimeStartSearch_txt.Text); }catch (System.Exception){//Ignore
        }
        try { dropTimeEnd = TimeSpanBuilder(dropTimeEndSearch_txt.Text); }catch (System.Exception){//Ignore
        }

        var matchedLoads = (
                        from loads in HOTLOADEntity.Loads
                        join drivers in HOTLOADEntity.Contacts
                        on loads.driver_id equals drivers.id

                        where 
                        loads.bol_num.ToString().Contains(bolSearch_txt.Text) &&
                        loads.pro_num.ToString().Contains(proSearch_txt.Text) &&
                        loads.quote_num.ToString().Contains(quoteSearch_txt.Text) &&
                        loads.ref_num.ToString().Contains(refSearch_txt.Text) &&

                        //Pick Date search terms
                        ((pickDateStart_dtpckr.SelectedDate == null || loads.pick_date >= pickDateStart_dtpckr.SelectedDate) &&

                        (pickDateEnd_dtpckr.SelectedDate == null || loads.pick_date <= pickDateEnd_dtpckr.SelectedDate)) &&

                        //Pick Time search terms
                        ((pickTimeStartSearch_txt.Text == null || pickTimeStart == TimeSpan.Zero || loads.pick_time.Value >= pickTimeStart) &&
                        (pickTimeEndSearch_txt.Text == null || pickTimeEnd == TimeSpan.Zero || loads.pick_time.Value <= pickTimeEnd)) &&

                        //Drop Date Search terms
                        ((dropDateStart_dtpckr.SelectedDate == null || loads.drop_date >= dropDateStart_dtpckr.SelectedDate) &&

                        (dropDateEnd_dtpckr.SelectedDate == null || loads.drop_date <= dropDateEnd_dtpckr.SelectedDate)) &&

                        //Drop Time search terms
                        ((dropTimeStartSearch_txt.Text == null || dropTimeStart == TimeSpan.Zero || loads.drop_time.Value >= dropTimeStart) &&
                        (dropTimeEndSearch_txt.Text == null || dropTimeEnd == TimeSpan.Zero || loads.drop_time.Value <= dropTimeEnd))

                        select new ViewModel
                        {
                            //Load properties
                            bol_num = loads.bol_num,
                            load_status = loads.load_status,
                            pro_num = loads.pro_num,
                            quote_num = loads.quote_num,
                            ref_num = loads.ref_num,
                            weight = loads.weight,
                            pieces = loads.pieces,
                            commodity = loads.commodity,
                            mileage = loads.mileage,
                            carrier_rate = loads.carrier_rate,
                            customer_rate = loads.customer_rate,
                            pick_date = loads.pick_date,
                            pick_time = loads.pick_time,
                            drop_date = loads.drop_date,
                            drop_time = loads.drop_time,
                            last_updated_time = loads.last_updated_time,
                            driver_id = loads.driver_id,
                            dispatch_id = loads.dispatch_id,
                            customer_id = loads.customer_id,
                            broker_id = loads.broker_id,
                            account_id = loads.account_id,

                            //Driver properties
                            driverContact_name = drivers.contact_name,
                            driverContact_phone = drivers.contact_phone,
                            driverContact_email = drivers.contact_email,
                        });

        LoadBoard.ItemsSource = matchedLoads.ToList();
    }
```

Modified Select on double click button for the datagrid

```
private void LoadBoard_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (LoadBoard.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            //Load model
            ViewModel SelectedItem = (ViewModel)LoadBoard.SelectedItem;
            Load loadModel = HOTLOADEntity.Loads.Find(SelectedItem.bol_num);
            using (HOTLOADDBEntities HOTLOADEntity = new HOTLOADDBEntities())
            {
                loadModel = HOTLOADEntity.Loads.Where(x => x.bol_num == loadModel.bol_num).FirstOrDefault();
                bol_txt.Text = loadModel.bol_num.ToString();
                loadStatus_cmbo.SelectedIndex = ParseStatus(loadModel.load_status);
                pro_txt.Text = loadModel.pro_num.ToString();
                quote_txt.Text = loadModel.quote_num.ToString();
                ref_txt.Text = loadModel.ref_num.ToString();
                weight_txt.Text = loadModel.weight.ToString();
                pieces_txt.Text = loadModel.pieces.ToString();
                commodity_txt.Text = loadModel.commodity.ToString();
                mileage_txt.Text = loadModel.mileage.ToString();
                carrierRate_txt.Text = loadModel.carrier_rate.ToString();
                customerRate_txt.Text = loadModel.customer_rate.ToString();

                //Dates & Times
                pickDate_picker.Text = loadModel.pick_date.ToString();
                pickAptTime_txt.Text = TimeStringBuilder(loadModel.pick_time.Value);

                dropDate_picker.Text = loadModel.drop_date.ToString();
                dropAptTime_txt.Text = TimeStringBuilder(loadModel.drop_time.Value);

                driver_txt.Text = loadModel.driver_id.ToString();
                dispatch_txt.Text = loadModel.dispatch_id.ToString();
                customer_txt.Text = loadModel.customer_id.ToString();
                broker_txt.Text = loadModel.broker_id.ToString();

                lastUpdated_lbl.Content = "Last Updated: " + loadModel.last_updated_time;
            }
            //Change Update/New button text
            update_btn.Content = "Update Load";

            //Enable copy & delete buttons
            delete_btn.IsEnabled = true;
            copy_btn.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```